# How to create a unit test to verify this code

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm learning unit test with javascript framework(Mocha) and I come across this source code on the internet but I don't know how to write a unit test so help me

this is the source code

```
const digitize = (n) => {
  r = n.toString().split('');
  r.forEach((el, i, a) => { a[i] = parseInt(el); })
  return r
}
```

I have tried to write

```
describe("digitize", function() {
   it('should call digitize', function() {
     expect(digitize(123)).eql([1, 2, 3]);
   });
});
```

the expected result is

```
8675309     [8,6,7,5,3,0,9]
123             [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I would expect your function to throw an error. Are you sure `digitize()` is correct?

Comment: Your function makes no sense, so any tests are unlikely to pass

Comment: I corrected the function

Comment: So do you still have a problem? What's the result of your test?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What problem are you having?

Comment: creating a unit test for that function

Comment: the result should be **786654 => [7,8,6,6,5,4]**

Comment: That *is* a unit test for that function, hence people's confusion. If you want to test a different case, add another test.

Comment: so what is the result or your unit test?
and why are you calling your function twice?

Comment: that's what I tried

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some research I have found this test to be working for me even though it's not perfect maybe someone with a better understanding than I can contribute

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

describe("digitize",function(){

   it('should separate digits', function() {

     assert.typeOf(digitize(123),'array');

   });

});
```